# Generic Type Aliases in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, type-alias

How can we declare Generic Type Aliases in swift 3.

I tried following :

```
typealias DictionaryOfStrings<T>  = Dictionary<T, String>
```

And producing error:

> error: type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Comment: `typealias DictionaryOfStrings<T: Hashable>  = Dictionary<T, String>`, I guess. Please try and let us know.

Comment: @EricAya ok I will keep in mind.

Comment: @Mohsin  typealias DictionaryOfStrings <T> = Dictionary<String, T> pl. try this

Answer (score 2):

```
typealias DictionaryOfStrings<T: Hashable> = Dictionary<T, String>

var dict = DictionaryOfStrings<Int>()

dict[1] = "One"
dict[2] = "Two"
```